# Not getting the correct width Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that is dynamically populated  with other divs of various widths, and i need to get the total width of all inside divs here is some code

```
    <div class="inner_wrpr">
    <div class="box>
    ...some content...
    </box>
    <div class="box>
    ...some content...
    </box>
    <div class="box>
    ...some content...
    </box>
    <div class="box>
    ...some content...
    </box>
    </div>
```

And here is the JS

```
    <script>
   var totalWidth = 0;

   $('.box').each(function() {
      totalWidth += ($(this).outerWidth(true));
   });
   $('.inner_wrpr').css({'width': totalWidth});
   </script>
```

But for some reason it only gives me the right width for the box divs which are narrower then the body but anything wider then the body returns the same width as the body
if you could help me with that i would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you set * { max-width: 100% } in CSS somewhere?

Comment: How is the width of the `.box` elements set?

Comment: And why wouldn't the width of the container adjust to the content, did you use position absolute, max-width or anything else to limit the width of the container ?

Comment: By min-width and it expands according to its content

Comment: Please post your CSS also

Answer (score 0):

You have added * { max-width: 100%; } or something like that in .box parent elements. So it doesn't allow widths greater than body's width. Check the screenshots:

[image]

Comment: No because the actual .box is wider then the body

Comment: In that case, do you have a fiddle or something to support your question?

Comment: No sorry as its dynamically generated content

Comment: No sorry its an internal web application

Comment: Could you provide screenshot of that bigger width .box with Inspector window open showing its width? (when you hover on that element name)